# slicknav does not work with jquery.mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, slicknav

I have a mobile page, where I have:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
```

And :

```
<div id="demo1"></div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a class="scroll" href="menukort1.php" data-transition="pop">Features</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="scroll" href="menukort1.php" data-transition="pop">Usage Instructions</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="scroll" href="menukort1.php" data-transition="pop">Examples</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What happens after the user clicks on each of the menu buttons is not we expect. There is a loaderbar displayed at the center of the pade and the link is not loaded. I think there is a problem between the javascripts, but is no error log on the console.

The link is: http://62-135-219-219-dynamic.dk.customer.tdc.net/admin/menukort.php

Thanks in advance,
Aleks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have extra closing div. 
At first line you have:

```
<div id="demo1"></div>
```

and at the last line

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my console you have a JS error about not being able to call something prior to initialization, suuggesting something is running too early:

"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove' jquery-1.11.0.min.js"

Should your slicknav initializer not be in a $(document).ready ?

And remember, JQM has it's own set of events if you're going for a multipage model (one single HTML doc with multiple pages) in which case you have to hook into something like this:

```
        $(document).delegate("div[data-role='page']", "pageshow", function () {
           //this runs when any new 'page' is shown
        }
```

For all JQM events [see here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).